# Angularjs + stop to update the data into variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am working with angularjs. I had some different kind of issue.

I have HTTP call. after HTTP request the response will be stored in two different variable. after I change data in variable means it will change automatically into other variable also.

```
$http.get('get/list')
        .success(function(data, status) {
           $scope.test1 = data;
           $scope.test2 = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {

        });
```

//sample json

```
    {
    "lists": [
        {
            "_id": "575e6d4bde006e3176bb9dc5",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "a"
                }, {
                    "name": "b"
                }
            ],
            "name": "fridge",
            "status": "done"
        }
    ]
}
```

After I will push json into  test1 variable.

```
$scope.addRow = function(comment1) {
            $scope.test1.lists.push({
                'name' : 'c'
            });

        };
```

But When I print the $scope.test2 it added automatically new added items also. (name = c).

Any Idea to fix this problem. I need to print test2 what getting in HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happened because `$scope.test1` & `$scope.test2` both are referring to same object in memory. Use `angular.copy` to create deep copy of object. So, `$scope.test1` & `$scope.test2` will no longer be alias of each other

```
$http.get('get/list')
    .success(function(data, status) {
       $scope.test1 = angular.copy(data);
       $scope.test2 = angular.copy(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the same relation of shallow copy / deep copy.

When you are storing values in `$scope.data1` and `$scope.data2`, you have to make a deep copy.

Use something like this.

```
$scope.test1 = angular.copy(data);
$scope.test2 = angular.copy(data);
```

It will create a deep copy instead and changing in `$scope.data1` won't effect `$scope.data2`

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML side, you can also cut the data binding between the view and the controller by putting two ':' as a prefix of the variable. Like this :

```
<div>{{::test2}}</div>
```

It's not really like your variable won't be updated again, but the changes will not be displayed into the web page.